# What's the word I should use for close calls

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, word-choice

Please allow me to ask a question, I set a goal in my work, which could not be accomplished in the first place, but it was finally accomplished. How should this situation be described? What word would you use to describe it?

Comment: Hello Anna. Great question! It depends. What was the goal you accomplished?

Comment: Hello Julien,Thank you very much for your reply, the goal I achieved refers to the goal at work, for example, my boss asked me to write ten JDS in one day, I thought I couldn't finish it, but in the end I did it

Comment: _I just managed to complete the task in time_?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is something like a near miss, but I don't know what the word is

Comment: [[ **(A)** "Not a Moment too Soon" , "under the Wire" , "at the last Moment" , "on the Dot" , "in the nick of time" ]] + [[ **(B)** "Achieved a tough target" , "Beat Expectations" , "Bested Myself" , "Met the Challenge" , "manage to nail it" ]] + MORE !!!

Comment: _Near miss_ would indicate that you failed to achieve the goal.

Comment: You've already used *one* "idiomatic standard" for this context in the question itself *(**a close call**)*. What's wrong with that? Why do you want a *different* expression? Alternatives include *[I just about finished in time, but it was a] **close shave / near thing***, but why not just stick with what you know?

Comment: If you set a goal which you think is more than you can do, you [raise the bar](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raise+the+bar) (from athletics).

Comment: When you say word, do you mean an expression?

Answer (score 1):

A ***stretch goal*** is one that may not even be fully achievable, but the pursuit of which will encourage a person or group to move beyond their so-called "comfort zone", and perhaps achieve more than they thought they could.

So you could say that you set yourself a stretch goal.

Comment: Never heard that expression...

Comment: Then count yourself lucky, because it means you haven't been exposed to as much nelogistic, bullsh*t management-ese as I have. :-) Here's an example of it being used, in a reasonably respectable source: https://hbr.org/2017/01/the-stretch-goal-paradox